# Treat id as VARCHAR when inserting and as NUMBER when querying on Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I need to map a legacy Oracle database table, lets call it `LEGACYOTB`, using [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate). Its primary key is a number sequence and this table assigned it a SQl type `VARCHAR()` that ranges from `'1'` to `'99999'`, —note: not `'00001'` but `'1'` without the zerofill. I cannot change this `id` column as of this moment to `NUMBER()` because simply it a legacy database.

My problem is: what would my Domain class should look like for it to able to:

1. Perform a query to the Domain class similar to this:

   ```
   SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(ID)) FROM LEGACYOTB
   ```
2. Perform an insert on that domain class:

   ```
   INSERT INTO LEGACYOTB(ID, ...) VALUES(...)
   ```

   Without encountering a similar sql error:

   > ORA-01722: Invalid number

I used `projection { max ('id') }` but rather than using the query on #1, it uses this instead:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM LEGACYOTB
```

Notice without the `To_NUMBER()` function— even though I mapped `id` as Long, it still treat `9` larger than `1000`. And that's also the same reason that causes `insert`s to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep the `String` entity field and switch from **Criteria API** to `HQL` or `SQL`, than you could get the new ID from a query like this:

```
select max(to_number(id)) FROM LegacyOtbEntity
```

Using Criteria API for such simple and static query is overkill anyway.

If you really need Criteria API, than you can create duplicate (read only) field annotated with `@Formula`:

```
@Formula("TO_NUMBER(ID)")
private Long numberId;
```

and than use it in the projection `Projections.max("numberId")`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the target of your question is to determine the next `id` for inserting a new row in your table `LEGACYOTB`.

I think best practice is to let the database do this job for you:

- create a database sequence to get next `id` value
- set the `id` by database trigger.

for example

```
create sequence LEGACYOTB_ID 
  minvalue 1 
  maxvalue 999999999999999999999999999 
  start with 991 -- current max value + 1
  increment by 1;

create or replace trigger "LEGACYOTB_ID_BIER" 
  before insert on LEGACYOTB  
  for each row
declare
  -- local variables here
begin

  select to_char(LEGACYOTB_ID.nextval)
    into :new.id
    from dual;
end;
```